# Using nuxt, how do I put the route name in the page title?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I want to set the page title to a different value for each page.

In regular Vue.js, I have done the following:

```
import router from './router'
import { store } from './store/store';

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.mutations.setRoute(to);
    document.title = store.getters.pageTitle;
    next();
}
```

How would I get that effect in nuxt?

That is, on both initial page load and when changing pages, I want the browser tab's title to change. For instance, from "My App - About" to "My App - Profile".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

from [nuxt docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#pages), in each `pages` component you can define the head function that returns the title of page i.e.

```
head() {
    return {
      title: "About page"
    };
  }
```

Comment: That works, mostly -- I can put the static page name in, but that doesn't handle all cases. I'd like to use the vuex store to compute the page name because it will contain an asterisk in some conditions. But combining that with the mounted() { document.title = } works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: head() {
    return {
      title: this.$route.name 
    }
  },

Comment: @CharlesBrandt that suggestion worked perfectly. thank you

Comment: What about nuxt3)

Comment: @modex98 haven't used Nuxt 3 yet but from docs it seems you have to use `useRoute` composable inside `setup` script/method.See the docs https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-route

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this, but I don't know if it is the "right" way. I use the `mounted()` function in `default.vue` for the initial page load and the `transition` property in `nuxt.config.js` for each page change. So, in `default.vue`:

```
...mapGetters(['appTitle']),
...mapMutations(['setRoute']),
mounted() {
    this.setRoute(this.$route.name);
    document.title = this.appTitle();
}
```

And in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
transition: {
    name: 'page',
    mode: 'out-in',
    beforeEnter (el) {
        this.$store.commit("setRoute", this.$route.name);
        document.title = this.$store.getters.appTitle;
    }
},
```

Comment: did you look at my answer?

Comment: This answer works well for me as I have a large app and manage all of my routes & meta programmatically in one js file; it makes sense to also manage titles there as well. I'd rather not have to deal with `title` across numerous page components all over the place.

Comment: Also: Using `document.title` seems to be legit, as vue-creator Evan You himself does so in [these title snippets](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/src/util/title.js).

Comment: How about server-side? `document.title` is only available on client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for Nuxt3 now that it's been released.

In Nuxt you can also use `document.title` to set the title. It's very straightforward if using `<script setup>` pattern:

```
<script setup>
document.title = useRoute().name;

... logic ...
</script>
```

Similairly if using the options API

```
setup() {
    document.title = useRoute().query;
},
```

*Documentation for useRoute: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-route*