# NuxtJS - Set head title/description on mounted?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
mounted() {
  // threads is a constant file
  this.thread = threads.find(t => t.id === this.$route.params.id)
},
data() {
  return {
    thread: null
  }
},
head: {
  title: this.thread.title,
  meta: [
    {
      hid: 'description',
      name: 'description',
      content: this.thread.body
    }
  ]
},
```

Basically, I have a constant file of json "threads" and I want to use it's properties to set head - title/description.

I'm getting this error:
Cannot read property 'thread' of undefined

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48286301/4636715

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [head documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head), type is **Object** or **Function**

So if you reformat your code a bit, you could write `head` like this

```
head() {
  const thread = threads.find(t => t.id === this.$route.params.id)

  return {
    title: thread ? thread.title : '',
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: thread ? thread.body : ''
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: I can't test this out right now, so let me know if this helps :)

Comment: oh.. it worked, but only for the description. The title did not change (the nuxt is still showing the default one defined on nuxt.config

Comment: I removed title template on nuxt config and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should define `thread` in data method

```
data () {
  return {
    thread: {
      body: '',
    }
  }
}
```

Also, the head should be define as method, not a property.

```
head () {
  return {
    meta: [
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: this.thread.body
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The head should be define as function with return value like data function.

``` head () { return { meta: [ {hid: 'description'} ]} }```

Answer (score 0):

aznable  Apparently you must remove null from here

```
thread: null => thread: ""
```

and insert this inside async methods

```
   async getId() {
    this.thread = await threads.find(t => t.id === this.$route.params.id)
   }
```

Best !